# Illegal attempt to dereference collection when querying using JPA relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes:

```
@Table(name = "PEOPLE")
@Entity
class Person {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
  Set<Car> cars;
}
@Table(name = "CARS")
@Entity
class Car {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  Person owner;
  @Column(name = "MODEL")
  String model;
}
```

I'm trying to query people by model. Running the following code **fails**, even though the connections between the tables are clear:

```
select mo from Person mo where mo.cars.model = ?
```

The error is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [...] with element property reference [model] [select mo from Person mo where mo.cars.model = ?]
```

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: * BTW, this is a simplified example. The failed code has several `OneToMany` connections. It's more of a tree, and the condition is on one of the leaves.

Comment: so read the JPA spec or any JPQL docs and see that you cannot dereference a collection like that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the relationship between the entities is already defined, you can use the `join fetch` syntax:

```
select mo from Person mo join fetch mo.cars c where c.model = ?
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that the relation is already defined in the annotations. No need to define the join. Magic :)

Answer (score 8):

`mo.cars` is a Set. You can't access the model property of a Set, because it doesn't have one. You need a join:

```
 select p from Person p 
 inner join p.cars car
 where car.model = :model
```

As always, [the relevant documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).