# Path expected for join for OneToMany relation in JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have the below query which I want to convert into JPA standard.
I am facing problem while adding path from Account to SubAccountRel class.

```
 public interface AccountRepo  extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "select * from C_ACCOUNT account 
                 join SubAccountRel rel on rel.sSubAccountId=account.accountSrcId 
                 where account.active = 1 and account.accountId = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
  List<Account> getAccountsByAccountId(String accountId);

  // I want to have a non native query for the above one
}
```

Below are the entity classes

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "C_ACCOUNT")
 public class Account implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "accountId")
  private String accountId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
  @Where(clause = "REL_TP='has external customer' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1")
  private List<SubAccountRel> subAccountRelList;

  @Column(name = "PKEY_SRC_OBJECT")
  private String accountSrcId;

  @Column(name = "active")
  private Integer active;

 // getters and setters

}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "C_PTY_REL_XREF")
 public class SubAccountRel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "ROWID_XREF")
  private String subAccountRelId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PTY_ID_2", referencedColumnName = "ROWID_XREF", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Account account;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PTY_ID_1", referencedColumnName = "ROWID_XREF", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private SubAccount subAccount;

  @Column(name = "S_PTY_ID_2")
  private String sSubAccountId;

  // getters and setters
}
```

How do I write OneToMany list mapping into JPA standard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the documentation for JPQL joins: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. Read it, and try something.

Comment: You are mixing native query with jpql in you query. So once the table "SubAccountRel" doesn't exist it will always fail. Try writting either JPQL or native query

Comment: Below link was helpful.             
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975468/illegal-attempt-to-dereference-collection-when-querying-using-jpa-relations/34975573