# Spring Data JPA @Query - creating new object from select

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I create new object in select statement.

```
  @Query("""
      select new com.myPackage.AuthorDTO(
            a.id,
            a.name,
            booksIds)
            from Author a
            join a.books.id as booksIds
            """)
List<AuthorDTO> getAuthors();
```

My record looks like this:

```
record AuthorDTO(Long id, String name, Set<Long> booksIds)
```

I have an error:
illegal attempt to dereference collection.
How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal attempt to dereference collection when querying using JPA relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975468/illegal-attempt-to-dereference-collection-when-querying-using-jpa-relations)

Comment: no, I  have a Join. Maybe in this example works because entity is in select